# Angular material auto complete should show options if the value matches with starting letter(s) of any word

Tags: autocomplete, angular-material, angular6

The first typed letter should match the first letter of every word of the result in the drop down.

Currently I am matching with any letter in the option like below but I should be match only starting letter(s) of any word in the option.

My current logic is below,

return this.allUniversities.filter(university => university.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1);

If the entry in the list is Industrial Designer, then this entry should show up if a candidate types the letter I or the letter D. It should not show up if the candiate types the letters ‘N, D, U, S’ etc.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is split the string and then check if the substrings start with the typed characters:

```
return this.allUniversities.filter(university => {
    return university.toLowerCase().split(' ').some(substr => substr.startsWith(filterValue));
  });
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-uggdlu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   is a stackblitz that shows it in action.

Comment: Thanks Fabian for the answer, it's working perfectly. Can you give solution for one more question.

The above answer should satisfy 3 scenarios,

Ex: Option is "Javascript is Angular"

1 . Option should show when I type  "Javascript is Angular"
2. Option should show when I type "Javascript" (or) "Is" (or) "Angular"
3. Option should show when I type "Is Angular"

Please provide the solution